# InjectionConstructor attribute in both Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder and Microsoft.Practices.Unity - what's the difference?

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container, wcsf

I see the InjectionConstructor property defined in both the Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder namespace and the Microsoft.Practices.Unity namespace.

Is one of these properties deprecated?  Can someone explain to me the difference between the two definitions?

Thanks!

Comment: A co-worker answered this question for me:  ObjectBuilder was the original version. Unity is a newer rewrite of ObjectBuilder.

WCSF uses ObjectBuilder, but the version of ObjectBuilder it uses has been "upgraded" and it has references to some of the Unity stuff.

Comment: That's an answer, not a comment. You should answer your own question and mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

A co-worker answered this question for me: ObjectBuilder was the original version. Unity is a newer rewrite of ObjectBuilder. WCSF uses ObjectBuilder, but the version of ObjectBuilder it uses has been "upgraded" and it has references to some of the Unity stuff.